# CSS3. Create animated background

Tags: html, css

I create two CSS classes:

How I can make a transition(first > second) between first and second CSS styles? Why it doesn't work?

[Live example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t3ohz/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="cross-row-line"></div>
on hover, it must be that in smooth   transition:
<br/>
<div class="cross-row-line-t"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.cross-row-line {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: background 2s linear;
}
div.cross-row-line:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5));
}
div.cross-row-line-t {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5));
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: The bold part should be a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.cross-row-line {
   pointer-events: none;  
}
```

Take out `pointer-events: none;`

This should work!

And if you want to know why please see the description below.

*Setting your Point-event to none.
The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.*

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t3ohz/4/ But it isn't animating smooth, why? Does this possible?

Comment: See this link: http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t3ohz/6/

The problem seems to be the background: linear gradient

I'm working on it, but maybe this fiddle can help you out.

Also check out this link: http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t3ohz/7/
Notice that the colours smoothly change.

Comment: I found the culprit!
Gradients can't be transitioned, so I geus I learned something new here as well :)

But this link does explain how you can bypass it. 
So by giving you this link, I still hope you have the full answer you need and I get the points! 
Thanks

http://codersblock.com/blog/gradient-animation-trick/